# Error When Connecting Umbraco site to SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, umbraco

I have created an Umbraco site locally which works fine. On deploying to a hosted solution i am getting the error "Umbraco cannot start. A connection string is configured but Umbraco cannot connect to the database."

Tried changing the connection string and confirmed with hosting company that the server is correct.

My connection string is as follows.

```
add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="server=Msql2017.ukwsp.com;database=xyz;user id=xyz;password='xyz'" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: Is as follows..?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from around the password...

Comment: Just removed the single quotes but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something is wrong with that connection string (or credentials) even though the hosting company claims it is valid.

If the hosting company is not using any sort of IP restrictions on which hosts can connect to the database, you could try connecting to the server manually with SQL Management Studio to confirm if the credentials are valid (this of course won't work if they have limited access to their own web servers IP range).

How did you restore your backup of your local SQL database to this hosting provider?

Depending on how the database was restored on their server, the credentials originally in place when setting up your account with the hosting provider could have been overwritten with whatever was in your backup from your local machine. This would result in you not being able to authenticate with the original credentials unless these are mapped to having access to the actual restored database.

If I were you, I would have the hosting company confirm that they can indeed still connect to the database with the credentials provided - and if not, have them fix the security mappings for you (since you shouldn't really have access to do this anyways).

Comment: Actually I just tried connecting to that server with SQL Mgmt Studio and it seems there's no firewall IP restrictions in place. I just get a credential error (using random credentials). So I would say, it would be very easy for you to verify whether the credentials you have, actually works. If they do your issue is elsewhere - if they don't, you should just reach out to your hosting provider.

Comment: I think you are correct. I can get to the server with Management Studio but get a password/username error. I restored the database onto the hosting server via a backup so its something to do with the login credentials.

Comment: As mentioned, you should then get in touch with your hosting provider and let them know your credentials are not working. They can add a new login to your database so you'll be able to authenticate correctly.

Comment: I spoke to the hosting company. The server needed to be proceeded by a port number, you can then connect via Management Studio. Also the website can connect which means it works. Thanks for your help with this issue.

Comment: No problem! - I'm happy to hear that it worked out for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your connection string (username and/or password) have an ampersand ('&') ? That can cause nasty issues.